# match start of string

Tags: .net, regex

I have some `"paths"` that are in a format similar to:

```
/Media/Default/images/Tulips.jpg
```

And I have the ability to get the "root path" which will return something similar to either:

```
http://example.com/Media/Default/
/another-prefix/Media/Default/
```

what I need to do is match the start of the "path" string with the end of "root path" string to return `images/Tulips.jpg`

What i really need is a generic regular expression that will compare pare the 2 `strings` do a `sort` of an overlay and trim at the greatest possible match. That way it will work if the inputs were changed to:

> Path: qwerty-some-random-string
>
> Root Path: junk-qwerty
>
> Result: -some-random-string

Comment: Why do you think a regex is suited for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Correct solution (with LINQ)

Tries all suffixes of `root` in descending order of length and stops when it determines that one of them is a prefix of `path`:

```
var path = "qwerty-qwerty-some-random-string";
var root = "aardvark-junk-qwerty-qwerty";

var prefix = root.Select((ch, i) => root.Substring(i))
                 .Where(pref => path.StartsWith(pref))
                 .DefaultIfEmpty("")
                 .First();
var result = path.Substring(prefix.Length);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/oLR1B)**.

---

Note: Initially I posted a regex solution here but it turned out that it was completely unworkable.

Comment: Jon's solution will not work correctly if the root path contains a repeated string: eg., root = "junkjunk-qwerty" or root = "path-data-data-qwerty'

Comment: or what if the string starts with 'aardvark'? :-P - heck any double letter has the potential to break this - am I looking at this right?

Comment: @Vortexfive: You are embarassingly correct. These problems can be solved, but there were additional problems with the regex solution that could not be solved at all. I replaced it with a LINQ solution. Thanks for spotting the problems.

Comment: Thanks for the aardvark nod :-D - I wonder where this is to be used (really with some file system? or with just strings...?) Should directories be treated as atomic? or can Root Path `abc-def-ghijkl` and Path `jklmno-pqrst` be correctly run through here as `mno-pqrst`? (i.e. should the `-` [or `/`] be treated as a delimiter? or just another character?)